# Use POST method with URL and Google Refine/ OpenRefine

Tags: rest, openrefine

OpenRefine http://openrefine.org/ allows URL generation using GREL as tokens.  I want to connect to an API which only supports a POST method .  Can I format the URL so it calls the REST API using POST?
Ref: https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Fetching-URLs-From-Web-Services

Comment: is the answer still "No" these days?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently, but it'd be a good enhancement request.  Click "issues" at the OpenRefine site URL that you posted.

Bonus points for patches/pull requests which implement the feature. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible by:

1. creating a curl command using grel and
2. then making the POST query in Jython.

Here is a list of tutorials for the step by step process:

- https://evanwill.github.io/_drafts/notes/refine-post-request.html
- https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/fetch-and-parse-data-with-openrefine#post-request

- https://www.getty.edu/research/tools/vocabularies/g_garcia_openrefine_workshop_itwg2020.pdf